# await HttpClient.SendAsync not throwing exception when expected

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

I have a Windows Phone 8 app containing code as follows:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(method, uri);
    try
    {
        var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequest);
        var httpResponse = await response;
        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            HandleError(httpResponse);
            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

If the client successfully connects to the server, I will get the expected results, including all the appropriate HTTP status codes and reason phrases.

If the client is unable to contact the server (e.g. incorrect domain/IP/port in the URL), the awaited task completes after some delay, with a 404 status and no reason phrase. The task never throws an exception. The task (the response variable in the code snippet) has the status of "ran to completion". Nothing about the result is indicative of the actual problem - be it networking failure, unreachable server, etc.

How can I capture more meaningful errors in the case where the URL points to a non-existent or unreachable server, socket connection refused, etc.? Shouldn't SendAsync be throwing specific exceptions for such cases?

FWIW, the client code is built into a PCL library using VS 2013 update 3 and running in the Windows Phone emulator, using System.Net.Http 2.2.28 from NuGet

Comment: What does `CreateHttpRequest` do? Perhaps it's creating a request that legitimately gets a 404 and not the other expected types of errors. Do you have sample method, uri, etc as well?

Comment: It makes no sense to get a 404 if `SendAsync` fails. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Simplified from my actual code; all I've simplified out is code which builds up the HttpRequestMessage - adds in content and headers

Comment: I would think you have to call `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` on the response to cause an exception to be thrown. The API does not indicate that responses like 404 will throw otherwise.

Comment: @mikez his problem is that he claims the URL is to an unreachable host, but he gets a 404 response back. not that he wants a 404 to throw.

Comment: @CoryNelson exactly... server could be shut down (incapable of responding) and SendAsync still gives me a 404

Comment: @CoryNelson I see. I read a little too quickly and the title is somewhat misleading then.

Comment: Is this going through some sort of proxy perhaps? The proxy could be responding with a 404.

Comment: @Jacob No proxies; didn't think you could use a proxy with the emulator... anyway, never set up such on the machine involved

Comment: If you don't expect an exception to be thrown, please edit your question so you are not asking why an exception isn't being thrown. I understand not wanting to get a 404 error if the server isn't even available at the given address, but it's not clear at all from the way you've written the question that it's the 404 error you really want to know about, versus the lack of an exception.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I was expecting SendAsync to throw an exception in cases where there is no server response, hopefully to get a meaningful diagnostic. The observed "404" behavior doesn't allow for that.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone's implementation of the .NET `HttpClient` is different from Desktop's implementation (wininet vs. custom stack). This is one of the incompatibilities that you need to be aware of, if there is a semantic difference for you.

In my simple test I do get a `ReasonPhrase` of "Not Found" on the phone emulator. Also you can see that the `Headers` collection is empty whereas if the server was found and actually returned a real 404 then there would be headers.